# How do I exclude scss files checking in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using jekyll static site generator for creating my website. Everything works just fine, but in Jekyll every scss file must have two `---` above:

```
---
---

@import "keyframes.scss" ;
@import "buttons.scss" ;
@import "footer.scss" ;
```

VSCode suggests not using those `---`, and it reports problems in my code:

[image]

But without those `---` the scss codes aren't recognized by jekyll.

So my plan is to exclude checking the CSS files (but without `files.exclude` which hides all the scss files), or perhaps better if VSCode can exclude only the specific `---` line and report the status of the file just it would.

Is there a way to do that?